# Where are my offline files if they are not in C:/windows/CSC?

Tags: windows-7, offline-files, file-location

I am using Windows 7 and am unable to find my offline folders.  They're not at c:/windows/csc.  I've unhidden hidden files and folders and protected operating system files.  Where else could they be?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the command

```
Takeown /r /f C:\Windows\CSC
```

on a command prompt (from [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/19847/how-to-move-offline-files-cache-in-windows-7)) before having a look in that folder? It might be that if you do not have ownership rights you cannot see everything that is in there.

Comment: It was an ownership issue.  Until I took ownership of each level of folder, the CSC folder properties showed it to only contained a few MB of data.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Jeff, if this was the correct answer you should be able mark it as such, there should be a "tick" underneath the voting buttons to mark an answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Your files should indeed be at c:\windows\csc, at least by default.

You can check this registry entry to see where yours are:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\BackupRestore\FilesNotToBackup

and look at the "Offline Files Cache" key in the right pane. I could find no other references in the registry to this, so it must be buried in some file or registry entry that cannot be read normally.

In case there is something going on with your explorer settings, you can also just open a command box, and type cd\windows\csc and see if that brings you to the directory.